# Appium with Android Hydrid App doesn't recognise element

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

I am writing automation tests for a Hydrid App on Android. I have 2 problems:

1. From Appium Inspector, I see an element with attribute

   ```
   resource-id: login_button
   ```

   so I click this button with

   ```
   androidDriver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
   ```

   and I get this error:

   ```
   "An element could not be located with..."
   ```

   Of course if I find element with

   ```
   classname "android.widget.Button"
   ```

   then it works. I asked developer, normally, `resource-id` would be like

   ```
   resource-id: <APP_PACKAGE_NAME>:id/login_button
   ```

   But he said for hydrid app he doesn't have `bundleID (APP_PACKAGE_NAME)`. Is it correct that we don't have `bundleID` for Hydrid APP? And why Appium Inspector can see

   ```
   "resource-id: login_button"
   ```

   but this element could not be found and clickable?
2. So I also tried to switch context to `WEBVIEW`, with this code:

   ```
   Set<String> contextHandles = appiumDriver.getContextHandles();
   Map<String,String> hashMap= new HashMap<String,String>();
       for (String contextname : contextHandles){
           if (contextname.contains("NATIVE")){
               hashMap.put("native", contextname);
           } else {
               hashMap.put("webview", contextname);
           }
       }
       //webview 
       androidDriver.context(hashMap.get("webview"));
   ```

   `contextHandles` has 2 values: `NATIVE_APP` and `WEBVIEW_<APP_PACKAGE_NAME>`. But when I set context to `webview`, I get error:

   ```
   "There is no such context"
   ```

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid application means - An application build by combination of both Native App View and Web View.

But at a time only one view will be available either Native or Web

If the view is Native, then you can inspect elements from UI Automator.

If the view is webview, then the UI automator will not show any hierarchy. For that you have to inspect in browser using the url - chrome://inspect/#devices

In your case you are saying that you are able to click on login if you use class name, but unable to click when you are using resource-id

There might be multiple locators having the same resource-id. Please check once and make sure you are using unique locator that might be Xpath or class name etc